# Get "Image Media Type" for "Named Places" type of ID

Tags: here-api

I looked up for a place using the Discover API as follows:

```
https://discover.search.hereapi.com/v1/discover?apiKey=<API_KEY>&q=Bremerton Boardwalk&at=47.5634276,-122.6236087
```

which responded with

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "title": "Bremerton, WA, United States",
            "id": "here:cm:namedplace:21002017",
            "resultType": "locality",
            "localityType": "city",
            "address": {
                "label": "Bremerton, WA, United States",
                "countryCode": "USA",
                "countryName": "United States",
                "stateCode": "WA",
                "state": "Washington",
                "county": "Kitsap",
                "city": "Bremerton",
                "postalCode": "98337"
            },
            "position": {
                "lat": 47.565,
                "lng": -122.62749
            },
            "distance": 339,
            "mapView": {
                "west": -122.86392,
                "south": 47.46469,
                "east": -122.59263,
                "north": 47.66075
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Now, when I am trying to retrieve the "Image Media Type" for the above ID using [this API](https://developer.here.com/documentation/places/dev_guide/topics_api/media-type-image.html), like follows:

```
https://places.ls.hereapi.com/places/v1/places/here:cm:namedplace:21002017/media/images?apiKey=<API_KEY>
```

or

```
https://places.ls.hereapi.com/places/v1/places/21002017/media/images?apiKey=<API_KEY>
```

then it responds with:

```
{
    "status": 404,
    "message": "Place with id '21002017' not found."
}
```

It works fine with IDs like `here:pds:place:840c23nb-55907767fca8456382de39d4bcf6f5e7`.

- Is there something special about IDs like `here:cm:namedplace:*`?
- How can I get images for such places where the Discover API returns such IDs?

Answer (score 0):

Please check this Request which can accomplish your task as below -

Lookup the places details with the discover API as below-

```
https://discover.search.hereapi.com/v1/discover?apiKey=<API_KEY>&q=Bremerton Boardwalk&at=47.5634276,-122.6236087
```

To look up a place by its HERE ID, the API includes the `/lookup` endpoint as below-

```
https://lookup.search.hereapi.com/v1/lookup?id=here:cm:namedplace:21002017&apiKey=<API_KEY>
```

> place id returned from discover endpoint.

Check the documentation here.

https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/dev_guide/topics/endpoint-discover-brief.html

https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/dev_guide/topics/endpoint-lookup-brief.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My question is how to get images for places with IDs `here:cm:namedplace:*`, and your answer talks about getting details for a place ID, which unfortunately which does not return the images. Please let me know if I missed something.

Also, please do not post your API keys in your answers. I have edited your post, pending community approval.

Comment: @Neo's update has been approved. You should be sure to recycle your API key to be safe.